# Simple Variadic C Function Parameters Error

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a very simple code. This code working on Linux Machine. 
But When I build with a Cross Compile and run on a Embbedded Hardware parameter,  Values of variadic functions are wrong. 
Is it about Compiling(Cross Compiling)? All application runnig fine but variadic function not working.

My Sample code below. Both of foo and formatString function working wrong.

```
void foo(char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int d;
    char c, *s;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    while (*fmt)
    {
        switch (*fmt++) 
        {
            case 's' :
                s = va_arg(ap, char *);
                printf("string %s\n", s);
                break;
            case 'd' : 
                d = va_arg(ap, int);
                printf("int %d\n", d);
                break;
            case 'c':               
                c = (char) va_arg(ap, int);
                printf("char %c\n", c);
                break;
       }
   va_end(ap);
}

void formatString(char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char buffer[100];

    va_start(args, format);
    sprintf(buffer, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    printf((char*)buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("\nProgram Started");

    foo("MSG : %d", 10);

    formatString("MSG : %d", 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define wrong. How wrong? What happens?

Comment: OK. As you saw, I pass 10 as parameter but when I read the variable in variadic function, this value is very different, for example "-1098376440". So I cant get given parameter values.

Comment: Cross compile for what kind of embedded platform ? Which compiler ? Programming environment, IDE ? If it doesn't work, the compiler may need some additional parameters in order to know how to properly pass variadic parameters for that specific platform. Including stdarg.h may be a good start.

Comment: Well first, inside formatString use vsprintf instead of sprintf. Modern compilers usually warn about mistakes like this one.

Comment: @svckr : yes, but in this case, `gcc -Wall` did not complain on his code. Oddly enough.

Comment: @wldsvc : Lokking this up a while ago, the flags -Wextra and -Wpedantic include warnings not reported by -Wall.  Granted, they are not likely to be as useful but can help in fringe cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your call to `sprintf` is incorrect. If you want to pass a `va_list` into `sprintf` you should use the `vsprintf` function.

Also, to be a little bit safer, consider using `snprintf` (`vsnprintf` in this case) instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks, When I watch the variable values at "Eclipse Variables Windows", values are very different. But when I use the vsprintf, everythink is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your formatString function is incorrect :

```
void formatString(char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    char buffer[100];

    va_start(args, format);
    vsprintf(buffer, format, args);
    va_end(args);

    printf("%s\n", (char*)buffer);
}
```

You should also consider vsnprintf, but I guess that it's only for test purposes.